# AutoLayout issue with an iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I am using a TableView with the UIImageView and UILabel on the Table Cell. I set constraints for UIImageView as like this:
[image]

And for the UILabel, I set constraints like this:
[image]

All the constraints set are working properly on every iPhone model as I want but it's not working as expected on iPad. There is a gap on the right portion of the cell. I want the UILabel to be filled completely with the margin of 8 on the right side.

[image]

How to fix this issue? Am I doing the wrong way? Any suggestion?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Are you setting UILabel width via constraints ?

Comment: I think this is a glitch in the display in xcode. I see that quite often and it seems to be clipping everything to 600 wide. Does it look like this when you actually run it in the simulator? In xcode, if you change design mode to wRegular/hRegular then look at preview it should look right.

Comment: @slonkar No, I haven't set the width constraints for the UILabel

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Yeah when I changed the mode to wRegular/hRegular, then I can see what I want in the design. But while running it in the simulator, even in iPhone, I see the design different from what I designed. :( The image appears on the center of the cell and label is not showing. Even the size of image is more than 103x103.

Comment: @bgsudeep Are the image and label inside the cell contentView or are there other views in between? Also are you using iOS8+ auto cell sizing or doing the cell sizing yourself in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? Would be worth you showing the code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also look in the debugger console for any errors related to not being able to satisfy constraints and the system having to break one or more.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using wAny hAny size class. The constraints added for image view and label looks fine. Check the table view constraints if you dragged table view in View Controller. Or else you can try giving aspect ratio to label, maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: With all the constraints you gave before, just set aspect ratio of image view. This is the second way to resolve your problem.